# Filter Expression - Service Bus Explorer

Tags: filter, message-queue, azureservicebus

I am trying to filter out messages in the queue to be able to find certain ones. I am not able to filter out the messages on nested array values. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am using https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer.

For example:

- Filter sourceObject='invoice' works
- But filter data/original/id='evt_1KCpUaKg1gx3TWpaSNrEy4dz' does not

Here is a snippet of the JSON messages:

```
{
    **"type": "finance-topic"**,
    "source": "stripe",
    "sourceObject": "invoice",
    "action": "update",
    "data": {
      "original": {
        **"id": "evt_1KCpUaKg1gx3TWpaSNrEy4dz",**
        "object": "event",
        "api_version": "2020-03-02",
        "created": 1640973976,
        "data": {
          "object": {
            "id": "in_1Jm09kKg1gx3TWpaArKJYrMM",
            "object": "invoice",
            "account_country": "US",
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering is operating on the custom headers (user/application properties).
You must have `sourceObject` propagated into headers, which is why filter expression works.

Comment: Thanks, Sean, that makes sense.  How do I propagate the sourceObject into the headers?

Comment: You can't mutate an existing message. This needs to be done by the sender when a message is sent or hardcoded by a subscription's rule via action.

Comment: Np. If this answers your question, don't forget to mark it as such to indicate to others that it's solved. Cheers.