# How to use filters in ServiceBusExplorer?

Tags: azure, servicebus, service-bus-explorer

I'm trying to filter out my Azure Dead Letter Queue messages in order to find a specific element from the deadletterqueue.

I downloaded the tool from https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer and make the connection between azure and the tool. I can see the Messages from my deadletterqueu here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPSyQ.png)

In the messages i have a json value with a partnerValue like this:

```
{
  "requestId": "6B454A4E-F8CB-4801-8874-8E97B149640E",
  "partnerValue": "114033",
  "productName": "myProductName",
}
```

I try to use the filter like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5Gee.png)

I read the artcile from https://www.sharepointeurope.com/azure-service-bus-topic-filters/ and tried a lot of things that didnt work, i tried:

- partnerValue like "517182"
- partnerValue = "517182"
- partnerValue like '517182'
- partnerValue = '517182'
- "partnerValue" like "517182"

But i dont work, i can't find the value (i'm sure that the value exist even if i do a basic exemple you productName" it dont work...)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

- Below filter expression should return messages,

  **partnerValue = '517182'**
- Check whether you are able to get messages using filter condition for active messages.
- Also check are you able to get messages using sys property.

[image]

- If any of the mentioned scenarios does not work, suggest you to try with another version of service bus explorer.

Reference [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70715550/filter-expression-service-bus-explorer)

Reference [link2](https://arminreiter.com/2016/03/azure-servicebus-filters/)